# Effects of decreasing semaphore value

Tags: process, semaphore

If I am trying to decrease semaphore value by one when the value is equal to 0, what happens ?

Is the process suspended ?

Answer (score 0):

The thread wich is trying to take(P, -1) the semaphore is suspended until another thread give(V, +1) the semaphore.

Comment: Does semaphore value remain as 0? What I mean is there is  a value changing after P(S, -1)

Comment: For example, by using semop() method, can we decrease a value of a semaphore from 0 to -1 or -2 ?

Comment: No, semaphore value will always be 0 or more.